# What is the WCF equivalent of an HTTPModule?

Tags: .net, wcf

Is there some uniform way I can implement behavior that occurs *around* a set of WCF service calls?  I'm looking for a simple way to handle cross-cutting behavior like logging, initialization, error handling, authorization etc.  With ASP.NET a lot of this is easy to implement as an HTTPModule.

Any helpful suggestions?

Comment: Great question -  exactly what I just google'd ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of extensibility points in WCF you can use for stuff like this. They include:

- [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx)
- [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx)
- [IParameterInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.aspx)
- Behaviors ([IServiceBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.aspx), [IEndpointBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior.aspx), [IOperationBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.ioperationbehavior.aspx))

Additionally, you can create custom ServiceHost classes to use either directly or through [ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702697.aspx), and then there's the entire channel stack model which is pretty extensible (if a bit complex at times).

Comment: Thanks for a bunch of good options!  It's going to take me a while to make sense of which approach works best in different scenarios and how to wire it all up.