# How can I implement my own digest security for a self-hosted WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, httpmodule

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the WCF equivalent of an HTTPModule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478695/what-is-the-wcf-equivalent-of-an-httpmodule)

I have a WCF service hosted in a Windows Service. I would like to secure it with digest security, but without using Active Directory.

I found an [old post](http://www.rassoc.com/gregr/weblog/2002/07/09/web-services-security-http-digest-authentication-without-active-directory/) that shows how to do this for an IIS-hosted service by implementing an HttpModule.

Can I add an HttpModule to a self-hosted WCF service, or is there another way to implement my own digest authentication?

Comment: What do you want this HttpModule to do? There is more than one extensibility point in WCF.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of adding that but wasn't sure if it was important or not to include. We want to use digest authentication but don't want to do it with active directory so I was mimicking a post I found here (http://www.rassoc.com/gregr/weblog/2002/07/09/web-services-security-http-digest-authentication-without-active-directory/) which implements it using an httpmodule and an alternative location with the users information.

Comment: Please be careful what you learn from Google. Did you notice that article is a decade old? You want to ask "how to use digest security with WCF?"

Comment: I suppose that could be another way of looking at the question. The key piece is that I need to implement digest authentication outside of active directory. I originally set up a web binding that I configured to use digest but I need to modify it to look at another resource for usernames/passwords. Someone gave me that article as a resource, but they were using it in an IIS hosted wcf service where it runs fine, but once I begin working in a windows service host, it no longer works. Do you think it would be better to create a new question with that focus instead of taking this direction?

Comment: I think it would be better to create a new question that asks, "How to use digest authentication in a self-hosted WCF service without Active Directory?" The current question focuses on making a particular, incorrect, implementation work.

Comment: Edited to make it ask "how to use digest security with WCF?" ... !

Comment: Thanks, @RogerLipscombe, but I actually thought it would be better if the new question omitted the entire concept of an HttpModule, especially the reference to the article from a decade ago. This is more of a WCF Extensibility question, and I was hoping to get it that sort of attention.